# Server.Transfer (not Response.Redirect) to other website

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webpage (aspx) **X** on which the user submits a value for use by another site **Y**. When the value is submitted, **X** needs to transfer the user to **Y**.
BUT, for security reasons, the client-ip (request variable 'REMOTE_ADDR') needs to be the outbound IP of **X** - NOT of the user! I would use Server.Transfer but this only works for internal pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to have the user use a website but that website shouldn't know the user's IP? Then the user can't go there themselves.

Comment: Not quite - website X should act as a gateway to website Y. Only through X (by ip-address validation) should access to Y be granted...

Comment: IP address validation seems like a silly way to do it. Giving the user some sort of token is generally how that is done.